# Accessing a webelement within a list of webelement in Selenium using Pything

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="w-30-ns W-100 pp">
                <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            </div>
             <div class="w-30-ns W-100 pp">
                <h1>My Second Heading</h1>
            </div>
             <div class="w-30-ns W-100 pp">
                <h1>My Third Heading</h1>
            </div>       
        </body>
    </html>
```

I would like to iterate thru all "class pp" webelements and find "h1" classes.  This is of course a simplified version of what I am trying to do.  The pp classes have MANY more children elements that I need to find and look at.  Creating a list up-front of all the "pp" web-elements would be great.

The code I have been trying is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

url2 = 'C:\\Users\\ed821\\Downloads\\TEST2.html'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url2)

titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pp")

for title in titles:
    heading = title.find_element_by_class_name("h1")  # << NoSuchElementException
    print("Title is:" + heading.text)
```

When I get to the "heading =" line, there is "NoSuchElementException".

Running in VSCode on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

url2 = 'C:\\Users\\ed821\\Downloads\\TEST2.html'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url2)

titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pp")

for title in titles:
    heading = title.find_element_by_tag_name("h1") 
    print("Title is:" + heading.text)
```

You are trying to search `h1` by class name but `h1` is tag name!

You can learn more about `find_element_by_tag_name` from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_elements_by_tag_name-driver-method-selenium-python/)

And you can learn more about other `find_element_by_<>` functions from [official documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: THANK YOU !!!   That fixed my issue.  I now realize that my problem statement was incorrect so I posted a follow-up :).  Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596909/finding-an-element-from-a-list-of-webelements-in-selenium-using-python