# Finding an element from a list of Webelements in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

class = "a1"This is a follow-up question to: [Accessing a webelement within a list of webelement in Selenium using Pything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594050/accessing-a-webelement-within-a-list-of-webelement-in-selenium-using-pything)

HTML File TEST2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="w-30-ns W-100 pp">
            <h1 class = "a1">My First Heading</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="w-30-ns W-100 pp">
            <h1 class = "a1">My Second Heading</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="w-30-ns W-100 pp">
            <h1 class = "a1">My Third Heading</h1>
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Trying to find all Class "a1".
The find_element_by_tag_name works.
The find_element_by_class_name does not work.  I get a "NoSuchElementException" Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".a1"}

```
from typing import List, Text
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'C:\\Users\\ed821\\Downloads\\TEST2.html'
driver.get(url)

titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pp")

for title in titles:
    heading = title.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")      ## This works
    heading2 = title.find_element_by_class_name("a1")   ## This does not
    print("Title is:" + heading.text)
    print("Also: " + heading2)
```

I need to search by "class" (and not tag).   The example above was of course just constructed for this example but the real web page contains too many similar tags.

Comment: If direct `class_name` doesn't works then have you tried css selector?

Comment: Can you give me an example?  I though this was a css selector.

Answer (score 0):

I was using double quotes where only single quotes are needed.

find_element_by_tag_name requires double quotes,
find_element_by_class_name requires Single quotes.

Documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

So:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'C:\\Users\\ed821\\Downloads\\TEST2.html'
driver.get(url)

titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pp")

for title in titles:
    heading = title.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")      ## This works
    heading2 = title.find_element_by_class_name('a1')   ## This works
    print("Title is:" + heading.text)
    print("Also: " + heading2.text)
```

Comment: I don't think "quote" is the issue here, cuz it is working for me with both single quote and double quote. and python perfectly supports both "double quote" and "single quote". any way i have found the issue in `print("Also: " + heading2)` here you are tying to concatenate `string` with `FirefoxWebElement` where as you should do `heading2.text`. But error doesn't shows that so, i haven't posted this as answer.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks... I was putting a breakpoint before that and I was causing an exception before the print.   No error with single quotes.  Error with double quotes for me.  Strange you don't see that ??

Comment: I didn't understand, post your answer, like this I have this problem, I have solved it myself, I solved my problem by doing this. :) this will help people of future if they have similar problem!